# coef() function and Debug message

Tags: r, lm, coefficients

1)I tried the below function but got an error message below.
could you please let me know what I did wrong with the commands?

```
#function:
sleep<-sleep
lm1<-lm(extra~group, sleep)
coef(lm(sleep$extra~sleep$group))
```

Error message:

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) :
>       argument "y" is missing, with no default

2)To understand the `coef()` function, I tried the example below provided by help. The weird thing is it was running without a problem, but after I got the error message above, when I re-ran the example again, it gave me the same error message.

```
x <- 1:5
coef(lm(c(1:3, 7, 6) ~ x))
```

Hope anybody can help me with this.

Comment: Can't reproduce this error. Could you add your session info? Specifically which `coef` function are you using? From which package?

Comment: ditto; also can't reproduce. Try restarting R and then running the code again.

Answer (score 1):

You already saved the linear model in `lm1`
Try coef on that

```
coef(lm1)
```

Comment: I tried "coef(lm1)" and still got the same error message.